# GTLRSheets_Color not holding value

Tags: swift, xcode, google-sheets, google-api

I am trying to set a value for "background color" as seen below but when I print the value after setting it, it simply shows nil? This makes absolutely no sense. Please help, I have exhausted all resources already.

Thank you.

```
let request = GTLRSheets_Request.init()

        request.repeatCell = GTLRSheets_RepeatCellRequest.init()


        let colbox = GTLRSheets_GridRange.init()

            colbox.startRowIndex = rowstart
            colbox.endRowIndex = rowend
            colbox.startColumnIndex = columnstart
            colbox.endColumnIndex = columnend
            request.repeatCell?.range = colbox

        let color = GTLRSheets_Color.init()
            color.blue = 60
            color.red = 47
            color.green = 77

            request.repeatCell?.cell?.userEnteredFormat?.backgroundColor = color
            request.repeatCell?.cell?.userEnteredFormat?.textFormat?.bold = true     
            request.repeatCell?.cell?.userEnteredFormat?.horizontalAlignment = "CENTER"

            request.repeatCell?.fields = "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat,horizontalAlignment)"

            print(request.repeatCell?.cell?.userEnteredFormat?.backgroundColor)

        let batchUpdate = GTLRSheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.init()
            batchUpdate.requests = [request]

        let createQuery = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsBatchUpdate.query(withObject: batchUpdate, spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId)

            service.executeQuery(createQuery) { (ticket, result, NSError) in

                    }
```

Comment: I think it something to do with intializing the cell, I am not familer enough with the google api to be sure. You can double check color is good by printing that, then have a play intilising ``` request.repeatCell.cell ```

Comment: From some quick googling the soltuions for similar issues in other languages use a fields parameter.

Comment: right you are, I'll tweak around with it a bit and post my answer if I get it. Thank you once more.

Comment: I have updated the code with the most logical instruction. I have tried working it around a bit but think I am giving up on this one for now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm thinking you should initialize both `cell` and `userEnteredFormat`, using something similar to: `request.repeatCell?.cell = GTLRSheets_CellData.init()` and `request.repeatCell?.cell?.userEnteredFormat = GTLRSheets_CellFormat.init()`.

Comment: OHHHHHHH your brain so sexy. It worked! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. I posted an answer with a bit more explanation and the appropriate references. Could you please consider accepting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You should initialize `cell` and `userEnteredFormat`.

#### Solution:

`cell` refers to an instance of [GTLRSheets_CellData](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GoogleAPIClientForREST/1.0.1/Classes/GTLRSheets_CellData.html), and should be initialized the following way:

```
request.repeatCell?.cell = GTLRSheets_CellData.init()
```

`userEnteredFormat` refers to an instance of [GTLRSheets_CellFormat](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GoogleAPIClientForREST/1.0.3/Classes/GTLRSheets_CellFormat.html):

```
request.repeatCell?.cell?.userEnteredFormat = GTLRSheets_CellFormat.init()
```

#### Reference:

- [GTLRSheets_CellData](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GoogleAPIClientForREST/1.0.1/Classes/GTLRSheets_CellData.html)
- [GTLRSheets_CellFormat](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GoogleAPIClientForREST/1.0.3/Classes/GTLRSheets_CellFormat.html)
- [Swift: Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html)